# Maximum file size with Servlets ServletFileUpload

Tags: java, mysql, apache, servlets

I want to load multiple files to a database for that, I load my file ServletFileUpload API, my question is until file size I can upload?, Because there is a limit threshold is passed if would have to be stored in a temporary file, however if you go over that limit are stored in memory.

Now I have the kind that makes this climb, but my question arises in the maximum size that I can assign that threshold.

And my other question is, if this in memory that information I can guess the deal as a data stream in order to insert them into a database, do not know if this is correct.

Comment: Did you meand a really big file stored in database? SQL or NOSQL? Why not a simple folder for that?

Comment: This is for a web type project, not going to upload large files, my question is the maximum upload size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your space is limited by the memory that got assigned to the JVM that runs that servlet. Have you tried to save the file while uploading into the filesystem? Using a buffered solution could save lots of memory.